# confusion about decidability

Tags: logic, computability

I just read the following sentence:

"[T]here is no effective decision procedure for determining whether or not an argument T/X is valid, where T is any subset of PA or RA and X is any sentence."

I don't understand how this squares with the fact that proof[m, k] is recursive, where m is the Godel number of a derivation of sentence with Godel number k.  For any alleged proof of X from T, can't we decide in a finite number of steps whether it's a proof in fact?  Isn't this what the quoted sentence denies?  Thanks!

[I now mention the source and context of the quote below.]

Comment: What does the notation T/X mean?  Does it mean just a claim that $X$ follows $T$, or a particular proof?

Comment: I thought it meant a particular proof, which is what was confusing me.  I can see why there would be no effective procedure to tell whether X follows from T (because there would be cases where X didn't follow but the procedure would never say so).

Comment: Is the upshot that the author must have meant that there is no decision procedure for telling whether every model of a set of sentences, T, is a model of a sentence, X (alternatively: whether X is provable from T), since there is a decision procedure for telling whether any sequence of sentences, T, is a proof of X (in some reasonable first-order proof system)?

Comment: To make the question clear enough to answer, I believe you need to include additional context for the quote, such as who said it and where, and more text on either side of the sentence that you are asking about.

Comment: Hi, Carl and Mauro.  The quote is from Yaqub's _Introduction to Metalogic_.  Here is the quote in context.

Comment: "...[T]he question of whether an argument whose premises are members of PA or RA [Robinson Arithmetic] and whose conclusion is some AV [arithmetic vocabulary] sentence is valid is undecidable.  More precisely...[insert quote above]."

Comment: Maruo, I think I understand the distinction between recursive and recursively enumerable: the class of valid arguments is recursively enumerable (semi-decidable), but not recursive.  I think that what had me confused was the difference between two notions of valid argument: one meaning that there is no model of the conjunction of the premises and the negation of the conclusion, and the other meaning that there is a finite sequence of formulas, where each is either an axiom or follows from a previous line by a rule of inference.

Comment: Am I right that the second notion is recursive (decidable), but the first is not?

Comment: $Prf_{\mathsf {PA}}(m,k)$ is recursive, but the *provability predicate* $Prov_{\mathsf {PA}}(k) := ∃x \ Prf_{\mathsf {PA}}(x,k)$ is not.

Comment: The right question is: What is the source from which you get the statement? As you already know, any proof in any reasonable formal system like PA or RA can be deterministically checked for validity. So if that statement is to be correct at all, it cannot be using "argument" to have the standard meaning. It should rather use "claim" or "theorem", not "argument", unless you permit unjustified arguments. The part that you quoted in your comment should be put in the question, but anyway it doesn't say either what "argument" was defined as.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I added a note to my original post directing the reader to my specification of the source and content of the quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the context of a paragraph on page 257, from which the quote is taken, the author is only saying that it is not decidable whether a given sentence follows from a given set of axioms of PA. The paragraph is all about logical validity, not about checking particular proofs.  When the author writes "An argument T/X" I believe the meaning is simply "the claim that X is a logical consequence of T".   Just before the quote, the author writes "There are many decidable PL sets such that the sets of all their logical consequences are undecidable". The reference to PA is meant to be an example of that phenomenon.

Comment: OK, thanks, Carl.